# Necessity of cloning classes for background processes running through rake?

Tags: rake, actionmailer, resque, rake-task

I have a resque worker class which works with `ActionMailer` and another that works with `Mail` directly. Here's a short example:

```
class NotificationWorker
  def self.perform(id)
    Mailer.delivery_method.settings = {
      # custom settings here
    }

    # Working with Mailer to deliver mails
  end
end
```

Assuming that there may be two workers running on `NotificationWorker`, I am not sure if these interfer each other. From my understanding, working directly on the `Mail` class would break functionality because this would result in both mailers using the same settings instead of their assigned ones. A solution would be to create a clone of such a class (which works with ActionMailer, but not with Mail AFAIK).

According to the Resque docs:

> Resque workers are rake tasks that run forever. They basically do
>   this:

```
start
loop do
  if job = reserve
    job.process
  else
    sleep 5 # Polling frequency = 5 
  end
end
shutdown
```

I am not familiar with rake besides the basic usage for rails apps. So can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not quite sure what you're trying to achieve here. I have a resque system which queue and delivers automated emails. I have it set up like this:

1) env.rb

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {...}
```

2) notification_job.rb # its the job not the worker that needs creating.

```
class NotificationWorker
  def self.perform(id)
    # Working with Mailer to deliver mails
  end
end
```

If you really need to work with mailer directly and each worker needs different settings then you may need to create a yaml file which relates to a variable that you give the worker on startup.

Comment: Sorry for my unclear question. I am trying to fetch and send mails based on settings given by a user. Therefore, every `Mail` or `ActionMailer` instance gets custom settings before fetching and sending. Since Settings are not stored in an instance but on the class itself (e.g. `MyMailer.delivery_method.smtp_settings=`) I feel like they override each other when the resque workers are working in parallel.

Comment: ah I've got you. nope, it should be fine as you had it. Each 'worker' is it's own process / version of the app. So as long as you're changing that processes mail settings then its no problem at all. Infact as one worker can change it's setting as much as it likes between sends there really shouldnt be an issue. the only way an issue could arrise is if you put as setting somewhere the worker cant access it. i.e. postfix or something.

Comment: that's what I've been looking for. Thanks!